# Tweet on behalf of users who have authenticated my app to post tweet?

Tags: python, django, twitter, python-social-auth

I have an app, using this app in which user can `sign-up via twitter`  and I have set permission of **Read, write, and direct messages** , So when user sign-up to my project he authorized me that I can post on-behalf of him. Also during signup I have got his o`auth-token and oauth-token secret`.

But I don't know how I can post tweet on behalf of that user. I try to submit a form at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json with parmas like status , my app key and secret , user oauth_token and secret but in response I am always getting this

`{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}`

I am using python-social-auth for sign up via twitter.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Ensure that you're making the request to the API via https:// and not via http://. Also, this might be helpful: http://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15244

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the user `access_token` with your request, that's the way Twitter knows which is the current authenticated user. With `python-social-auth` you can do:

```
# given a user instance (and assuming Django ORM)
social = user.social_auth.get(provider='twitter')
backend = social.get_backend()
form_data = {
    'status': 'The new twitter status goes here'
}
response = backend.get_json(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', 
    method='POST',
    auth=backend.oauth_auth(social.extra_data['access_token']),
    data=form_data
)
```

Comment: Is there any api, which will allow me to post a status by just taking 3 parameters - eg:  api.PostStatus(text, screen_name, password)  ?